# I need a .bat that searches a directory for specific text

Tags: file, batch-file, search, text, directory

I need to search a certain directory's files (every file) for the text "aura".

How would I do this?

I need it to search every file in this directory, and output it onto a .txt file on the Desktop.

If someone could do this for me, that would be much appreciated, because I don't know how.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd C:\path\path
findstr aura "*.*" > %userprofile%\Desktop\output.txt 2> nul
```

I hope this works for you, I didn't test it. (I used my phone to answer)

Comment: It doesn't output into a .txt file, how do I do this?